# Using Entity Framework (C#), is there a way to encrypt fields so that they can only be decrypted if the user is logged in?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption, asp.net-identity

I am new to Entity Framework.  I'd like to store a field in the database that cannot be decrypted on the server side (for example, by a DBA).  I could generate a per-user key on the client side and store it on the client side, but I thought I would ask the community if there is a standard practice for this problem.  What is the recommended approach to this problem?

Comment: By curiosity how will you store the key?

Comment: Yeah, becuase this totally is one fo the ideas coming up every couple of months and generally not working and being the result of somoene NOT thinking things through. The standard practice is not to do it - AT ALL. In certain use cases (password) this ALSO is not stored encrypted (hashes are NOT encryption, they are not reversible).

Comment: I've never heard this requirement before but it seems reasonable. Use the Data Protection API so that only the specified windows account can decrypt.

Comment: Sounds like a case for IDataProtector/IDataProtectionProvider

Comment: When you connect to a remote SQL Server an use Integrated Security = true a few things occur.  First you need the local and remote machines to be in the same group.  Then you are using windows encryption to send data between local and remote machines.  Also Integrated Security the user credentials have to be store on the local and remote machines and the database security will only allow access to the database when the credentials are verified.